# How to add custom property to data source with Jython?

Tags: jython, ibm-was

We are using Jython to configure a data source in WAS. The data source created OK, with some default custom properties. Now I need to add another property, without deleting the other propertues. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions on the Knowledge Center link below to create a new data source custom property using Jython:

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-dist&topic=txml_configcustom

The link provides the following steps:

1. Identify the parent ID:

   ```
   newds = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/JDBCProvider:JDBC1/DataSource:DS1/')
   print newds
   ```

   Example output:

   DS1(cells/mycell/nodes/mynode|resources.xml$DataSource_1)
2. Get the J2EE resource property set:

   ```
   propSet = AdminConfig.showAttribute(newds, 'propertySet')
   print propSet
   ```

   Example output:

   (cells/mycell/nodes/mynode|resources.xml#J2EEResourcePropertySet_8)
3. Get required attribute:

   ```
   print AdminConfig.required('J2EEResourceProperty')
   ```

   Example output:

   Attribute     Type
   name         String
4. Set up attributes:

   ```
   name = ['name', 'RP4']
   rpAttrs = [name]
   ```
5. Create a J2EE resource property:

   ```
   print AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', propSet, rpAttrs)
   ```

   Example output:

   RP4(cells/mycell/nodes/mynode|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_8)
6. Save the configuration changes.
7. In a network deployment environment only, synchronize the node.